# Jquery - how to load everything except the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a WordPress addition which loads full post content (normally it shows exceprts) when asked to. I did my code like this:

```
$(".readMore").click(function() {
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$(this).parent("p").parent("div").children("div.text").slideUp("slow", function () {
    $(this).load(url + " .text", function(){
        $(this).slideDown("slow");
    });
});
$(this).parent("p").fadeOut();
return false; });
```

And it works. But I don't want images to be loaded. I tried .text:not(img), but it didn't worked. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even if your `load` selector had worked (and/or the one that Martin suggests in his answer), the downloads of the images would have started by the time jQuery filtered out the images. jQuery processes the selector from the "URL" in `load` by taking the content and appending it to a `div`, and then applying the selector to extract what you ask for. I suspect even just putting the `img` elements in a disconnected `div` will start the download. Obviously YMMV and you'd want to test with your target browsers.

Comment: Yup, the requests get made -- at least, they do on Chrome and Firefox when Firebug is enabled: http://jsbin.com/ecoxo4/2

Answer (score 1):

The trick, of course, is preventing the images from being downloaded unnecessarily by the user's browser; not *displaying* them is easy.

I only have two browsers were it's easy and convenient to tell what's downloading: Chrome and Firefox+Firebug. [In my tests](http://jsbin.com/ecoxo4/4), Martin's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289293/jquery-how-to-load-everything-except-the-images/5289332#5289332) using `*:not(img)` results in the images being downloaded (although not displayed) in both Chrome and Firefox+Firebug. (I emphasize "Firefox+Firebug" because Firebug can change the behavior of Firefox on occasion, and so it may well be changing its behavior here, although I don't think it is; more on that below.)

It took some tweaking, but this seems to do the trick (more on testing below):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) {
    var div = $("<div>").html(data);
    if (stripImages) {
      // Find the images, remove them, and explicitly
      // clear the `src` property from each of them
      div.find("img").remove().each(function() {
        this.src = "";
      });
    }
    $(targetSelector).append(div.children());
  },
  error: function(jxhr, status, err) {
    display("ajax error, status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/anake5) The "Include big image" checkbox includes a large file from NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day (APOD).

The key there was setting the `src` of the `img` elements to `""`. On Chrome, just removing the elements was enough to prevent Chrome starting the download of the images, but on Firefox+Firebug it not only started downloading them, but continued even when the download took considerable time. Clearing the `src` causes Firefox to abort the download (I can see this in the Firebug Net console).

So what about IE? Or Firefox without Firebug? I only did unscientific testing of those, but it's promising: If I run my live example of [Martin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289293/jquery-how-to-load-everything-except-the-images/5289332#5289332) on either IE or Firefox without Firebug in a VM, I see the VM's network interface working hard, *suggesting* that it's downloading that big APOD picture. In contrast, if I run [my solution above](http://jsbin.com/anake5) in that same environment (with caches cleared, etc., etc.), I don't see the VM network interface doing that work, *suggesting* that the download is either not being started or is being aborted early on.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder, it is almost "it" :) The only problem now is, it loads entire page into the div. I've tried modyfing you script (replacing `var div` with `var div = $("<div class=\"post span-14 featured\">").html(data);` and loading url with `url += " .text"`, but it's not helping. But anyway, it's a milestone ;)

Comment: @Tomek: Once you've loaded it into the div, you can retrieve only the bits you want and put them in your actual target element. That's what `load` does: First loads the whole thing into a div, then applies the selector. Something like this: http://jsbin.com/anake5/2

Answer (score 0):

`.text *:not(img)` will select every descendant from .text that is not an image, so in theory it should work.

Comment: The thing is, by the time it's applied, I'm pretty sure the downloads of the images will have started. jQuery processes the selector from the "URL" in `load` by taking the content and appending it to a `div`, and then applying the selector. I suspect even just putting the `img` elements in a disconnected `div` will start the download. Obviously YMMV and one would want to test with your target browsers.

Comment: They do get made, at least on Chrome and Firefox w/Firebug: http://jsbin.com/ecoxo4/2

Comment: T.J. - I've tried your method, but the images are still there.

Comment: @Tomek: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by *"T.J. - I've tried your method, but the images are still there."* I hadn't presented a method (well, I did for about two minutes before I thought better of it). But I have now, in [my new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289293/jquery-how-to-load-everything-except-the-images/5290064#5290064).

Comment: @Tomek: Side note: If you want someone to know you've replied to them, put an `@` in front of their name in your comment -- StackOverflow will let them know. (*Thank you*, though, for including the dots; people tend to leave them off.)